# Remove Card from Apple Pay used in a subscription

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay, in-app-subscription, recurring-billing, wallet

I just want to know if a user removes a Credit/Debit card which is used in a recurring subscription through Apple Pay, what should happen?

Comment: The app in which the Apple Pay has used to buy subscription should ask for new card, or it should continue as it is?

Comment: as far as I know, nothing, the payment processor still has the card details saved and can continue to attempt to charge them.